# Django 1.8.1 : A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I was working with django-1.8.1 and everything was good but when I tried again to run my server with command bellow, I get some errors :

command : `python manage.py runserver`

errors appeared in command-line :

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", l
ine 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 170, i
n __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 50, in
 load_middleware
    mw_class = import_string(middleware_path)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 24,
in import_string
    six.reraise(ImportError, ImportError(msg), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 658, in reraise
> 
>     raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line
> 21, in import_string
>     module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1) ImportError: polls doesn't look like a module path [24/Apr/2015 21:50:25]"GET /
> HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

error appeared in browser :

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

Also, I searched the web for this issue and I found something but they were not working for me.

This is my settings.py : `

```
    """
    Django settings for havij project.

    Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

    For more information on this file, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

    For the full list of settings and their values, see
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
    """

    # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


    # Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
    # See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

    # SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
    SECRET_KEY = '9va4(dd_pf#!(2-efc-ipiz@7fgb8y!d(=5gdmie0cces*9lih'

    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

        INSTALLED_APPS = (
            'django.contrib.admin',
            'django.contrib.auth',
            'django.contrib.contenttypes',
            'django.contrib.sessions',
            'django.contrib.messages',
            'django.contrib.staticfiles',
            'polls' ,
        )

        MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
            'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
            'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
            'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
            'polls',
        )


    ROOT_URLCONF = 'havij.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'havij.wsgi.application'


    # Database
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }


    # Internationalization
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True


    # Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
    # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    `
```

And here is the urls.py :

```
        from django.conf.urls import include, url
    from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        # Examples:
        # url(r'^$', 'havij.views.home', name='home'),
        # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Thanks for your answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've put your app name, `polls`, in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. It should only go in INSTALLED_APPs.

Answer (score 0):

In other Django version (1.7) can be for 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: because the answer was said above.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
python manage.py migrate
```

it will create all tables for "admin"